# Google Maps v3 - Muliple Markers - Different Colors

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, google-maps-api-3

I'm using coldfusion to populate a google map - and I want different colored markers for things

Using Google Maps API v3

This code works but they are all 1 marker color - green is always showing - I cannot get the different colors showing.

Thoughts?  Thanx for any input

```
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script> 

 <script type="text/javascript"> 

 var locations = 
[ 
<cfloop query=due>
<cfoutput>
<cfquery name="info" datasource="data">
SELECT * FROM data
WHERE id = #due.id#
</cfquery>
<cfif info.gpslat is not "">["#info.id#", #info.gpslat#, #info.gpslong#,      #info.id#],</cfif>
</cfoutput>
</cfloop> 
]; 

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
  zoom: 14, 
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.19, -114.48),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
 }); 

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 

 <cfloop query=due>
<cfquery name="info" datasource="data">
SELECT * FROM data
WHERE id = #due.id#
</cfquery>

       var marker, i;

<cfif info.gpslat is not "">    
   <cfif due.data is 'yes'>
   var image = 'red.png'; 
   </cfif>
   <cfif due.data is 'no'>
   var image = 'green.png'; 
   </cfif>
</cfif>
</cfloop> 


 for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {   
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]), 
    map: map,
    icon: image
  }); 

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) { 
    return function() { 
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]); 
      infowindow.open(map, marker); 
    } 
  })(marker, i)); 
 } 


 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing javascript and ColdFusion code and so the marker image taken is the last one available in your loop. Something that may work would be

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 

    var locations = 
    [ 
    <cfloop query=due>
    <cfoutput>
    <cfquery name="info" datasource="data">
    SELECT * FROM data
    WHERE id = #due.id#
    </cfquery>
    <cfif info.gpslat is not "">['#info.id#', #info.gpslat#, #info.gpslong#,#info.id#,<cfif due.data is "yes>'red.png'<cfelse>'green.png'</cfif>],</cfif>
    </cfoutput>
    </cfloop> 
    ]; 

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
        zoom: 14, 
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.19, -114.48),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }); 

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {   
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]), 
        map: map,
        icon: locations[i][4]
    }); 

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) { 
            return function() { 
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]); 
                infowindow.open(map, marker); 
            } 
        })(marker, i)); 
    } 
</script>
```

Code is not optimized also... but that's another thing :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you need an array or something. This loop:

```
<cfloop query=due>
<cfquery name="info" datasource="data">
SELECT * FROM data
WHERE id = #due.id#
</cfquery>

       var marker, i;

<cfif info.gpslat is not "">    
   <cfif due.data is 'yes'>
   var image = 'red.png'; 
   </cfif>
   <cfif due.data is 'no'>
   var image = 'green.png'; 
   </cfif>
</cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Which I assume is meant to do either / or and result in more than one kind of marker on the map - actually productes one variable for "image" .. it's going to do:

```
var image = 'red.png';
var image = 'red.png';
var image = 'green.png';
```

But each set statement is going to overwrite the next on in the script.

Instead create a JS function that you call that brings back either red or green. and in the space where you do:

```
icon: image;
```

you would now do:

```
icon: getimage(var1, var2);
```

where var1 and var2 equal info.gsplat and due.data. Either that or the whole thing needs to go inside the loop so you are writing out each marker in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS Sprite techniques](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/) to use a variety of markers:

```
var mImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("/i/Images/IconsLarge.png", 
    new google.maps.Size(34, 35), 
    new google.maps.Point(0, vPos), <--- set the vertical position to match your sprite offset.
    new google.maps.Point(10, 34)
); 
//insert marker
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: mImage,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    map: map
});
```